# "Legal matters" as a navigation title on a website

Tags: word-request

I want to have some links like the imprint and privacy policy in a navigation on my website. I am just wondering what would the best title be for this above those links. It should be a generalized word, and legal matters or maybe legal aspects sound a bit specific and long.

Is there maybe one single word, which sums that legal stuff up?

Comment: Unless your business is in the law itself or you have an aversion against informality, 'Legal Stuff' is fine.  If you need a single word, then 'Legalese' works.

Comment: And what about 'Legal'? So that people on the website can see "Here I find imprint and privacy policy and the terms!"?

Comment: I would note that right at the bottom of this page is a link with the single word [legal](http://stackexchange.com/legal). Clearly it's good enough for SE. "Legalese" is better if you want people to consider it informal, in the sense of "I don't like to do this, but I have to because my lawyers say so."

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks for that. Post it as an answer, I gonna accept that as the right one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like [Jonathan Garber](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/748/jonathan-garber) said, it really depends on whether or not you want to be formal.

If you do, then you should probably use “Legal Terms” or “Terms of Service”. However, if you want a quick link, you can still use “Legal” on its own, which is formal enough, just like this website shows.

And if you specifically do *not* want to be formal, the you can use “Legalese”, or even “Legal Stuff”.

Comment: You are very welcome.